# Whatever happened to nStatic?

Tags: .net, static-analysis

[Wesner Moise](http://wesnerm.blogs.com/) used to write about a static analysis tool called [nStatic](http://wesnerm.blogs.com/net_undocumented/nstatic/) for .NET which looked really exciting.  This was a few years and nothing has been published since.

Does anyone know what's happened to the tool, or in fact, Wesner himself?!  I hope he's OK, his [last post](http://wesnerm.blogs.com/net_undocumented/2008/12/reboot.html) about nStatic development explained that he'd had some health and life imbalance issues.

Comment: No idea? It looked very promising! I just pinged Wesner

Comment: Looks interesting. What would have been the differences between `nStatic` and `FxCop`?

Comment: Did you ever hear back?  I heard he's still alive as someone mentioned something he recently said.

Comment: nop, no news so far, I know Wesner had some post recently on jan 3rd, but not concerning NStatic, http://wesnerm.blogs.com/

Answer (score 1):

In January 2015 Wesner answered your question himself in [this post](http://wesnermoise.com/blog/2015/01/plans-for-year-2015).
It looks like he has not given up on the tool and still thinks that "*NStatic might change software*".

According to those posts, his plans for 2015 included:

> - Releasing a NConvert semantic code conversion tool [early in the year]
> - Kickstarter for NStatic, [in February]

He also mentioned he had been "*contacted by recruiters from two different major tech companies*", which may (or may not) explain why we have no news of either NConvert or NStatic one year later.

Answer (score 0):

I will be back. Life happens when you are developing a startup on your own. I just did not have the time to finish. I will complete my work in a few years.

I have a website wesnermoise.com that I am relaunching with a new blog and exciting work on

- natural language
- static analysis

The technology that I have is ahead of its time.

I have been taking 30 online courses a years for a number of years after the MOOC to keep abreast of new technologies especially in AI and to learn new subjects that I didn't get a change to pick up in college.

Also, I took jobs in backend and distributed development.  This will help me deliver a cloud-based solution rather than a desktop one.

Comment: Very nice to hear from you again Wesner! And exciting to hear about your plans!